# Bad jump destination in escrow Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testnets, remix

This is an escrow smart contract deployed on testnet Ropsten: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xd8be8771520addd926a3b454b4ea89a31d753359#code

When calling function start(address seller, address thirdParty) from geth node like this:

```
sc.start.sendTransaction("0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b", "0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4", {from:"0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d", value:"0x3b9aca00", gas:1000000});
```

It creates a new transaction https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x0fe57a93d9618f915fa822ba1b727147e04c11b23e523d6382ddd879020d98d9 throwing the following error:

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]
```

The code of start() function:

```
function start(address seller, address thirdParty) returns (uint) {
    uint escrowId = numEscrows;
    numEscrows++;
    escrow memory e;
    e.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    e.seller = seller;
    e.buyer = msg.sender;
    e.amount = msg.value;
    e.recipient = seller;
    e.status = 1; // started
    escrows[escrowId] = e;

    escrowStart(e.buyer, e.seller, e.thirdParty); // Log

    return escrowId;
}
```

The event called is:

```
event escrowStart(address buyer, address seller, address thirdParty);
```

Strange thing is that the same code works well on Solidity Browser ( https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ ) but not on testnet.

Any help/ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certainly because you're sending ETH to a function without the `payable` modifier. Without that modifier, solidity assumes that it is never intended to receive ETH and so will compile to `throw` (which appears as an invalid jump) if it does.

Comment: Thx! That's the reason of the error!